# Why can I have a const pair<const T, T> reference to a pair<T, T>?

Tags: c++, reference, const-correctness

I found out by chance that I can have a `const std::pair<const int, int>&` reference to a `std::pair<int,int>`:

```
#include <utility>
int main()
{
    std::pair<int, int> p{1,2};
    const std::pair<const int, int>& ref_ok{p}; // why does this work?
    std::pair<const int, int>& ref_invalid{p}; // then why does this not work?
}
```

Why is this possible, considering that `const std::pair<const int, int>` and `std::pair<int, int>` are different types that are not related by inheritance?

Comment: `auto const& r{ p };` then print out the addresses of `&p`, `&r`, and `&ref_ok`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`const std::pair<const int, int>& ref_ok{p};` is actually materializing a temporary `std::pair<const int, int>` initialized to the same values as `p` and the reference initialization is extending the lifetime of the temporary to that of the lifetime of the reference.

`std::pair<const int, int>& ref_invalid{p};` is not allowed because non-`const` references can't bind to a temporary.

The following code example shows that `ref_ok` is not actually a reference to `p`. Changes to `p` have no effect on `ref_ok`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::pair<int,int> p{1,2};
    const std::pair<const int, int>& ref_ok{p}; // why does this work?

    std::cout << p.first << ' ' << ref_ok.first << '\n';

    p.first = 5;

    std::cout << p.first << ' ' << ref_ok.first << '\n';
}
```

Output :

```
1 1
5 1
```

Live example : https://godbolt.org/z/8bfM7fYbx

Comment: Does this always happen if the type of the variable is convertible into the type of the reference? If so, how does the compiler know that pair<T,T> is convertible into pair<const T,T>? So it must somehow "know that conversion path by inspecting the template parameter's conversion capabilities"?

Comment: @phinz As long as `T` is copyable, `T` is always convertible to `const T`

Comment: @phinz This requires that there is an allowed implicit conversion. `std::pair` has an implicit constructor that accepts any other pair type, as long as both of that pair's element types are convertible to its own element types.

Comment: Can you please help me, which of these constructors https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair is called for the copy? If I understand correctly, it needs to that have 4 template types (two for the pair type and another two for the argument type). I don't find it. EDIT, I see T1 and T2 are already implicit, so it is number (5)?

Comment: @phinz #5 Two of the template arguments are part of the constructed pair type. The constructor only needs 2 extra template arguments, for the other pair's template arguments.